# for...of loop halts for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I have the following `setInterval` running on a Discord bot:

```
client.setInterval(async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://pso2.kaze.rip/eq/');
        if (response.status !== 200) return;

        const data = await response.json();
        const cache = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile("./cache.json"));

        if (data[0]["time"] !== cache["time"]) {
            const guilds = client.guilds.filter(guild => { return client.provider.get(guild, "alerts") });

            let i = 0;
            for (let guild of guilds) {
                i = i + 1;
                let settings = await client.provider.get(guild[1], "alerts");
                let eqs = data[0]["eqs"].filter(item => { return settings["ships"].includes(item["ship"]) });
                let format = [];

                if (!client.channels.get(settings['channel'])) return;
                let channel = client.channels.get(settings['channel']);

                if (eqs.length <= 0) return;
                if (eqs.length > 0 && eqs.length !== 10) {
                    for (let eq of eqs) {
                        format.push(`\`SHIP ${eq['ship']}:\` ${eq['name']} (${eq['jpName']})`);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    format.push(`\`ALL SHIPS:\` ${eqs[0]['name']} (${eqs[0]['jpName']})`);
                }

                let time = moment(data[0]["when"]);
                let string = `:watch:**IN 40 MINUTES:** (${time.format("HH:mm")} JST)\n${format.join('\n')}`;

                if (channel.type == "text" && channel.permissionsFor(client.user).has("SEND_MESSAGES")) {
                    //await client.channels.get(settings['channel']).send(string);
                    console.log(`${i} Sending alert to guild ${guild[1]}`);
                }
                else {
                    console.log(`${i} Skipping guild ${guild[1]}`);
                }
            }

            console.log('writing file...');
            await fs.writeFile("cache.json", `{ "time" : "${data[0]["time"]}" }`);
            console.log('done');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}, 10000, client);
```

Everything is working as expected, except that after the 93rd iteration the loop stops and nothing else is executed (until the next iteration of the `setInterval` happens). This is odd because the `guilds` array has over 400 objects in it, and I even checked the 94th element for the checks I'm doing inside the loop and it passed all of them. What could be causing this?

Comment: Maybe because there is 93 elements in `guilds`.

Comment: There are over 400. I forgot to mention I even checked the 94th element for the checks I'm making inside the loop and it passed all of them. Let me edit the question with those details.

Comment: If you aren't using the `guild` variable and want to use the index `i` instead, then why not usin a normal `for(let i = 0; ...)`?

Comment: I don't really need the index, I only added that to make sure the last element being printed wasn't actually the last one in the array. I'll test with a regular `for` loop though, maybe it will work.

Comment: Nope, same result.

Comment: `if (!client.channels.get(settings['channel'])) return;` <-- well you do `return` from inside....

Comment: Yup, I just noticed that. I should be using `continue` instead, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the loops exits than the line

```
if (!client.channels.get(settings['channel'])) return;
```

is running.

So I am guessing you want to keep on looping so you should be using `continue` to exit that iteration, not `return`